# css and image is not shown on php-fpm and nginx pods

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, nginx

When I try to deploy a website with php-fpm and nginx on kubernetes by providing the website files(hello.php, styles.css and image) the page is not showing both css and the image, only in case of deploying it by Docker image. In case I provide this file via hostPath I do not have any problems with it, and site is working correctly. I have provided the additional information below about files that are used for Helm Chart, Dockerfile and hello.php

I have the following Dockerfile, with all the required files beign copied to /var/www/html

```
# Use the php:7.2-fpm as the base image
FROM php:7.2-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy the contents of the /qa directory into the /var/www/html directory in the image
COPY app-chart/contents/qa /var/www/html
```

And here is the deployment in Kubernetes that I use for static website:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "app-chart.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "app-chart.name" . }}
  annotations:
    configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload: "hello-php"
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ include "app-chart.name" . }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: {{ .Values.maxSurge }}
      maxUnavailable: {{ .Values.maxUnavailable }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ include "app-chart.name" . }}
      annotations: 
        rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}
    spec:
      volumes:
        {{- if eq .Values.environment "local" }}
        - name: hello-page
          hostPath:
            path: /app/contents/local
        {{- end }}
        - name: nginx-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Values.configMaps.nginxConfigMapName }}
      containers:
        # php app
        - image: {{ .Values.image.php }}
          name: app
          {{- if eq .Values.environment "local" }}
          volumeMounts:
           - name: hello-page
             mountPath: /var/www/html
          {{- end }}
        # nginx
        - image: {{ .Values.image.nginx }}
          name: nginx
          volumeMounts:
            {{- if eq .Values.environment "local" }}
            - name: hello-page
              mountPath: /var/www/html
            {{- end }}
            - name: nginx-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
              subPath: nginx.conf
```

With the following values for helm:

```
environment: qa # local or qa
replicaCount: 3
maxSurge: 1 
maxUnavailable: 1
image:
  php: test/php-fpm-app:latest # php:7.2-fpm
  nginx: nginx
configMaps:
  nginxConfigMapName: nginx-config
nodePort: 30000
serviceType: NodePort  # Set to "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer" as desired

configMapSourceFile: "contents/hello-qa.php"

ingress:
  domain: test.com
```

And here is the ConfigMap with a nginx.conf

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    events {
    }
    http {
      server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        
        # Set nginx to serve files from the shared volume!
        root /var/www/html;
        server_name _;
        index hello.php;

        # location / {
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # }

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /hello.php?$args;  # Redirect root path to hello.php
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
      }
    }
```

My hello.php website:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Hello World Version 2!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<h1>Hello World from QA V8</h1>'; ?>
        <p>This page is served from Pod: <span style="color: blue;"><?php echo gethostname(); ?></span></p>
        <img src="k8s-image.png" alt="K8s Image">
    </body>
</html>
```